# Plymouth glitch when I power off PC

Tags: systemd, gdm, plymouth, 21.04

So, I use 21.04 and when I power off PC then I can see that keyboard is off, but Plymouth is frozen, then in about 15 seconds PC gets off as well. I looked at logs and find 2 errors, is there any way to fix it? Ubuntu 21.04 with 5.11.0-17 kernel

```
16:32:41 kernel: Error opening PCM device front:0: No such file or directory
16:32:41 kernel: Gdm: Failed to contact accountsservice: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Accounts: Transaction for accounts-daemon.service/start is destructive (local-fs-pre.target has 'stop' job queued, but 'start' is included in transaction).
```

Comment: I think I am experiencing the same problem. Sometimes, my laptop freezes with a black screen and does not shut down.  I have the `Gdm: Failed to contact accountsservice` error in my logs as well. Is this the only `Transaction for accounts-daemon.service/start is destructive` error in your logs, or do you see other instances of this message? For example, I see this error while the system is unmounting partitions [as in this question I posted](https://askubuntu.com/q/1344686/100356).

Comment: @PJSingh Yeah, I have the same error log